# How to load Kibana Visualizations with python script using REST requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, kibana

I want to automate creating Visualization and Dashboard on Kibana with a python script. I was able to do this with cURL command on terminal, PUTting data to 'http://localhost:9200/.kibana/visualization/visualization_name'.

---

However, I faced a problem when I added this snippet to my python script.

First I tried hard coding my cURL command to docstrings and passing it to terminal:

```
import subprocess
command = '''curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/.kibana/visualization/test_visual -d'{"title":"test_visual","visState":"{\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"params\":{},\"schema\":\"metric\",\"type\":\"count\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"SYSTEM\",\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\",\"size\":100},\"schema\":\"segment\",\"type\":\"terms\"}],\"listeners\":{},\"params\":{\"addLegend\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"defaultYExtents\":false,\"shareYAxis\":true},\"type\":\"line\"}","description":"","version":1,"kibanaSavedObjectMeta":{"searchSourceJSON":"{\"index\":\"id_1\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}},\"filter\":[]}"}}' '''
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
print(output)
```

This returned:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   731  100   313  100   418   4012   5358 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6741
b'{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"}},"status":400}'
```

---

I have also tried using requests library:

```
import requests
url = 'http://localhost:9200/.kibana/visualization/test_visual'
data = '''{"title":"test_visual","visState":"{\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"params\":{},\"schema\":\"metric\",\"type\":\"count\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"SYSTEM\",\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\",\"size\":100},\"schema\":\"segment\",\"type\":\"terms\"}],\"listeners\":{},\"params\":{\"addLegend\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"defaultYExtents\":false,\"shareYAxis\":true},\"type\":\"line\"}","description":"","version":1,"kibanaSavedObjectMeta":{"searchSourceJSON":"{\"index\":\"id_1\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}},\"filter\":[]}"}}'''
response = requests.put(url, data=data)
print(response)
```

Which also returned 400

---

I know that the cURL is correct as I was able to run this fine in <s>shell script</s>/terminal and was able to confirm from Kibana dashboard. Please help me understand my error. Thank you.

I'm using ES 2.2.0 and Kibana 4.4.0

**EDIT**

I realized that I can't run it in shell it either if I save the command in a variable ...

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out yesterday, sooo I'll answer my own question because I know someone else will struggle with this at some point in time. And I need some more explanation regarding inconsistent behaviours in shell if someone with more knowledge stumble across this.

---

**Working code**:

```
import requests
url = 'http://localhost:9200/.kibana/visualization/test_visual'
data = """{"title":"test_visual","visState":"{\\"aggs\\":[{\\"id\\":\\"1\\",\\"params\\":{},\\"schema\\":\\"metric\\",\\"type\\":\\"count\\"},{\\"id\\":\\"2\\",\\"params\\":{\\"field\\":\\"SYSTEM\\",\\"order\\":\\"desc\\",\\"orderBy\\":\\"1\\",\\"size\\":100},\\"schema\\":\\"segment\\",\\"type\\":\\"terms\\"}],\\"listeners\\":{},\\"params\\":{\\"addLegend\\":true,\\"addTooltip\\":true,\\"defaultYExtents\\":false,\\"shareYAxis\\":true},\\"type\\":\\"line\\"}","description":"","version":1,"kibanaSavedObjectMeta":{"searchSourceJSON":"{\\"index\\":\\"id_1\\",\\"query\\":{\\"query_string\\":{\\"analyze_wildcard\\":true,\\"query\\":\\"*\\"}},\\"filter\\":[]}"}}"""
response = requests.put(url, data=data)
print(response)
```

So the changes I have made it to work were to escape the forward slash as well as the double quotes in visState value object and searchSourceJSON value object.

---

This string will still NOT WORK with

```
os.popen(command).read()
```

nor

```
subprocess.check_ouput(command, shell=True)
```

---

Another important note I realized was that the behaviour will change depending on the shell you are using. I have done all my testing on MINGW64 (Git bash for Windows).

In **MINGW64**, you can copy paste this command directly into the shell:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/.kibana/visualization/test_visual-d '{"title":"test_visual","visState":"{\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"params\":{},\"schema\":\"metric\",\"type\":\"count\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"SUBMITDATE\",\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\",\"size\":100},\"schema\":\"segment\",\"type\":\"terms\"}],\"listeners\":{},\"params\":{\"addLegend\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"defaultYExtents\":false,\"mode\":\"stacked\",\"shareYAxis\":true},\"type\":\"histogram\"}","description":"","version":1,"kibanaSavedObjectMeta":{"searchSourceJSON":"{\"index\":\"id_1\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}},\"filter\":[]}"}}'
```

However in **Windows PowerShell** (with cURL installed), you must triple the quotes for all strings inside data:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/.kibana/visualization/test_visual -d '{"""title""":"""test_visual""","""visState""":"""{\\"""aggs\\""":[{\\"""id\\""":\\"""1\\""",\\"""params\\""":{},\\"""schema\\""":\\"""metric\\""",\\"""type\\""":\\"""count\\"""},{\\"""id\\""":\\"""2\\""",\\"""params\\""":{\\"""field\\""":\\"""SYSTEM\\""",\\"""order\\""":\\"""desc\\""",\\"""orderBy\\""":\\"""1\\""",\\"""size\\""":100},\\"""schema\\""":\\"""segment\\""",\\"""type\\""":\\"""terms\\"""}],\\"""listeners\\""":{},\\"""params\\""":{\\"""addLegend\\""":true,\\"""addTooltip\\""":true,\\"""defaultYExtents\\""":false,\\"""shareYAxis\\""":true},\\"""type\\""":\\"""line\\"""}""","""description""":"""""","""version""":1,"""kibanaSavedObjectMeta""":{"""searchSourceJSON""":"""{\\"""index\\""":\\"""id_1\\""",\\"""query\\""":{\\"""query_string\\""":{\\"""analyze_wildcard\\""":true,\\"""query\\""":\\"""*\\"""}},\\"""filter\\""":[]}"""}}'
```

That would mean you would have to modify the above solution to output the targeted string depending on the shell you are using.

---

In conclusion, if you are using Python, stick to Python libraries that can handle request. Try to use shells that are closest to Unix shells.